# AngularJS ngcontroller to be reloading data periodically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this working implementation af a angularJS app which fetches some links from an URL and paint them.
However the links on the URL are being updated constantly,  I would like to update periodcially this $scope.listlinks, let say every 10 seconds.

I tried playing with setInterval with no luck.

Javascript

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('ListLinksCtrl', 
function get($scope, $http ) {
  $http.get('http://example_url.com/my_changing_links_json').then(
       function(res){$scope.listlinks = res.data;});
}
);
```

HTML

```
<div id="cnt1" ng-controller="ListLinksCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="singlelink in listlinks">
        <a href="{{ singlelink.url }}"> 
           {{ singlelink.destination }} 
        </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what was the problem with ``setInterval`` ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

While jvandemo's answer will work, I think it can be improved slightly. By using `setInterval`, it breaks the dependency injection convention that Angular follows and makes unit testing of the controller difficult.

Angular doesn't currently support `setInterval` through its built-in services, but you can use the `$timeout` service to produce the same functionality. I'd change the controller to this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  // Function to get the data
  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('style.css')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      // Your code here
      console.log('Fetched data!');
    });
  };

  // Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
  $scope.intervalFunction = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.getData();
      $scope.intervalFunction();
    }, 1000)
  };

  // Kick off the interval
  $scope.intervalFunction();

});
```

Comment: This didnt work for me when the code was written inside the controller scope. The function is fired but the model on the page isn't being updated.

Comment: This works for me, but it continues running even when you navigate away from the controller, and worse yet, it spawns another interval every time you navigate back to the controller!

Comment: does tail recursion work properly in javascript (i.e. is there no risk of slowly filling up the stack somewhere as `intervalFunction` seems to call itself ?)

Comment: so use service instead of controller, that way it will happen only once.

Comment: Angular has an $interval service now that you can use, and you can cancel it using $destroy, so it will stop when you navigate away from the view: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: using $interval and $scope.on('$destroy', function(){ // clear your $interval here }) is a better option.

Comment: Just an additional note... $scope.intervalFunction doesn't need to be in $scope unless it affects the view. Might save you a watcher...

Answer (score 9):

### 2016

---

**$interval** is made for this:

```
    $interval(function() {
        // your stuff          
    }, 1000);
```

Don't forget to inject `$interval` in your controller

```
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',function($scope, $interval) {
      $interval(function() {
            // your stuff          
      , 1000); 
}]);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 4):

You can use the setInterval function but you need to encapsulate your logic in a function like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  // Function to get the data
  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('style.css')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        // Your code here
        console.log('Fetched data!');
      });
  };

  // Run function every second
  setInterval($scope.getData, 1000);

});
```

I've created a working plnkr for your at: http://plnkr.co/edit/vNCbBm45VYGzEQ7cIxjZ?p=preview

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think this needs an $apply because the getData function is called outside of the angular framework and therefore the $scope will not be updated. Alternatively use angular's $interval or $timeout

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds off of drew.walker's answer, but makes it so that changing controllers will not spawn multiple endlessly running refreshes. It also runs `getData` immediately, instead of delaying it 1 second.

It depends on you using Angular routes and setting Ctrls in them. If you don't, you'll need another way to determine if this controller is in scope.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $route, $timeout) {

    // Function to get the data
    $scope.getData = function() {
        ...
    };

    // Get the data immediately, interval function will run 1 second later
    $scope.getData();

    // Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
    $scope.intervalFunction = function() {
        var currentCtrl = $route.current.$$route.controller;
        var currentlyRunning = $rootScope.myAppMainCtrlRefreshRunning;
        //do not run if the MainCtrl is not in scope
        //do not run if we've already got another timeout underway (in case someone jumps back and forth between
        //controllers without waiting 1 second between)
        if (currentCtrl === "MainCtrl" && !currentlyRunning) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.myAppMainCtrlRefreshRunning = true;
                $scope.getData();
                $scope.intervalFunction();
                $rootScope.myAppMainCtrlRefreshRunning = false;
            }, 1000);
        };
    };
    // Kick off the interval
    $scope.intervalFunction();

});
```

Comment: `$$` to my knowledge indicates stuff internal to angular - which is subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change to order to make it work:

From

```
$scope.intervalFunction();
$rootScope.myAppMainCtrlRefreshRunning = false;
```

to

```
$rootScope.myAppMainCtrlRefreshRunning = false;
$scope.intervalFunction();
```

Otherwise the loop only executes once

Answer (score 0):

You can try the implementation of promises/deferred using $q provider.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this it worked fine for me.

$scope.intervalFunction = function(){
     if ($location.$$absUrl === "current url") {
      $timeout(function() {
      $scope.showAllEmployeeTracking();
      $scope.intervalFunction();
      console.log("loading Interval")
    }, 10000)
    }
  };

  // Kick off the interval
  $scope.intervalFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use Angular **$interval** and **$destroy** providers
Example:

```
var stop=$interval(function () {
            function_call();
        }, 12000)

        $scope.stopInterval = function () {
            if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
                $interval.cancel(stop);
                stop = undefined;
            }
        };

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
            $scope.stopInterval();
        });
```