# Stop AngularJS auto refresh when clicking an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I base my code from this post [AngularJS ngcontroller to be reloading data periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416458/angularjs-ngcontroller-to-be-reloading-data-periodically) on reloading data every 3 seconds.

My problem now is, when I click something, I want to stop the auto refresh. After that, the auto refresh will start again.

Say for example, when I click a button stop, the auto refresh will stop. and when i click button start it will start fetching data again every 3 seconds.

here's my js

```
var newsfeed = angular.module('newsfeed',[]);

newsfeed.controller('newsfeedController',function($scope,$http){
     var getPosts = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost/must_sns/main/all_status').success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
                console.log(data);
        }); 
    }
    getPosts();
    setInterval(getPosts, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `clearInterval` function:

```
newsfeed.controller('newsfeedController', function($scope, $http) {

    var interval;

    function getPosts() {
        $http.get('http://localhost/must_sns/main/all_status').success(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    $scope.start = function() {
        interval = setInterval(getPosts, 3000);
    };

    $scope.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };

    // Start loading
    $scope.start();

});
```

Now in HTML you could use `start/stop` methods:

```
<button ng-click="start()">Start</button>
<button ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. it's working on button (as my question). But on side note, is this applicable when clicking/focusing my mouse in a textarea?

Comment: when using `ng-focus` after the mouse lose focus on the textarea how can i fire up `start()` ?

Comment: Use `ng-blur="start()"`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the returned intervalID.

```
var myInterval = setInterval(getPosts, 3000);
```

then you can stop it again in another function (for example called by a button press like so:

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

On a sidenote: Angular supplies a `$interval` service that might be more suitable to your cause.

Comment: but how can I apply $interval? sorry, noob question

Comment: You need to inject it into your controller, see @sma answer for an example with $interval

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular wrapper for setInterval:  `$interval`.  Then you can do something like this:

```
var newsfeed = angular.module('newsfeed',[]);

newsfeed.controller('newsfeedController',function($scope,$http, $interval){
     var getPosts = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost/must_sns/main/all_status').success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
                console.log(data);
        }); 
    };

    getPosts();
    var timer = $interval(getPosts, 3000);

    $scope.stopTimer = function () {
         $interval.cancel(timer);
    }
});
```

You store the reference to the timer in a variable `timer` and then you can call the `cancel` function on `$interval` to stop the timer.

If you use the Angular wrapper, then it makes your code much more testable.  You can mock the `$interval` actions using the `$interval` object in the `ngMocks` library.  Its better to rely on the Angular wrapper for global functions like that so that your code is more testable.