# not able to dynamically update the view when data is changing

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of files in a server which I am looping though and constructing a JSOn and saving it as a separate file. I am using python for this. Works quite well. Now the scope is the number of files in the directory will increase/ change throughout the day..and I am running the script every 10 min to rewrite the json...the file name stays same and  i am calling it in a single page html document using angular.js..Again fairly simple...But now I am having problem when the JSON is changing I am not seeing any change on the page unless I reload the page. Could I do something about this?

With angular I am using

```
$http('something.json').success(callback function with some argument data)
```

and in the markup something like

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in data">{{x.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18416458/1444541

Comment: @JaKXz--well...if I really want to set  time interval it would be fairly easy. I am wondering if I could do without that and work with an idea of a listener which responds to the change. Could that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to $http is one-time operation which happens after page load like this:

```js
$http('something.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
});
```

- angular is kickstarted
- ng-controller containing $http request is evaluated and request for 'something.json' is sent
- ...
- when your json arrives, your success function is called with data from json
- view (html template) is updated with new data

Angular keeps your model (eg $scope.data) and UI (expressions in template) up to date, but it doesn't update external resources.
If you want to periodically poll for changes in 'something.json'
you can use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service as suggested in [JaKXz's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416458/angularjs-ngcontroller-to-be-reloading-data-periodically).

Comment: @josef--that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining this. Really appreciate it