# When reloading data periodically in AngularJS data is blinking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I needed  something to reload data from an external REST Api periodically, so I found and used the code from this question: [AngularJS ngcontroller to be reloading data periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416458/angularjs-ngcontroller-to-be-reloading-data-periodically)

The code is copied in here:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  // Function to get the data
  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get('style.css')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      // Your code here
      console.log('Fetched data!');
    });
  };

  // Function to replicate setInterval using $timeout service.
  $scope.intervalFunction = function(){
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.getData();
      $scope.intervalFunction();
    }, 1000)
  };

  // Kick off the interval
  $scope.intervalFunction();

});
```

Only difference to my code is I am using ngResource to get the content instead of $http (I don't know if this makes a difference).

I am just printing the data in my view, and the problem is that every time it updates (once every second) the text blinks. It disappears while the new data is recovered? Obviously I would like it to just update smoothly without blinking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is timing.
Browser parses your empty data set and renders the template and then, when the data comes, it will parse again the data and redraw. These $digests may cause flickering.

There are 2 ways to avoid this:

1) use the `ng-cloak` directive on the parent element

2) make a false boolean, set it to true when the data has loaded and add an `ng-if` with that boolean on the parent element

Also, you can override the `$digest` method and see exactly how many times is called and what triggers that.
Please mind that most of the angularjs default services are triggering a $digest (e.g. any network request via `$http` will trigger a `$digest` after the success/error methods are executed).